# recursion in java without local variables

Tags: java, recursion

I was currently reviewing some code from a colleague and found a use of recursion I have never seen before.

I reduced it, so what he basically does is:

```
public class Main {
    static class Test {
        private static final int MAX = 10;

        private int mValue = 0;

        void test() {
            System.out.println( mValue );
            mValue++;
            if (mValue < MAX) {
                test();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        final Test test = new Test();
        test.test();
    }
}
```

When I would use recursion, I would give all needed variables as parameters and then have a return value giving something back, or using one of the parameters to provide a container object where a result could be written in. So that every recursion has it's own scope of data to work on.

I looked around but also every example on the net does it the way I would do it.

So could this lead to any errors? Some inconsistencies in the object? Is there a difference between this and calling different private methods manipulating the member variable?

brgds,

J

Comment: Hello all, thanks for the answers. I wanted to make sure this is basically ok before I start to complain about the indeed not thread-safe access to the object, which was my major point against his implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As long as your logic is thread-safe** (immutable object or containing relevant locking), there's no reason to strictly prefer parameter over global class' field even when recursion occurs.

Of course, as long as, the concerned field represents object's state and not a simple ugly helper variable...

Answer (score 2):

This will work as expected, as long as a single instance of the `Test` class never runs `.test()` concurrently.

**Edit**

@Itay made me realize, that the word "concurrently" is wrong here - it should be "competingly" in the sense of "not cooperating with or not knowing of each other". I am sorry, the german (my native language) word "Konkurrenz" and the english word "Concurrency" have a slightly different meaning.

**/Edit**

If this is guaranteed, putting `mValue` in the class scope, not local scope, can improve locality and cache hit rate, also removes some parameter passing - alltogether it trades some performance gain against encapsulation.

Comment: Not only concurrently but also sequentially - if you call this method twice the second run will do nothing. Unless this is the required behavior, it can be considered a problem.

Comment: Please forgive a non-native-english speaker: With concurrently I ment "not cooperating with each other". I will edit the answer and use "competingly" instead.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem if the recursive method will be called twice on the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

> So could this lead to any errors? Some inconsistencies in the object?

In practice, it is not preferred way to implement recursion.

The condition `(mValue < MAX)` should only be affected within from recursive method. if not, your recursion may end un-expectedly.